# Android Studio and "error: cannot find symbol class"

Tags: android-studio

I there:

I am working in the last version of Android Studio, and I have the next problem. I am generating code (.java classes), so my code is generated outside Android studio and copied into the folder of the project. When I try to run the code, it shows the following message

> error: cannot find symbol class XXXXX

Where XXXXX is a class that exists (I tried with other classes and it happens the same). The class is well defined, its visible by Android Studio but it still fails.

The code is generated, so it is copied directly into the folder of the project and I think it is the problem.

What I tried to do: (according to other answers).

- Rebuild the project.
- Close and open Android studio.
- File - Sync with file explorer.
- File - Sync Project with Gradle Files.
- File - Invalidate Cache Restart.

And those solutions do not work.

However, this works:

- Create a class using Android studio and now I can generate the class and replace the file. **Apparently, Android Studio (or Gradle) is unable to recognize a file created outside Android Studio.**

What I can do?.

I need to create many classes so I can't create each file manually.

Is there are an internal database?.

Comment: Probably you're forgot the package name?